# floating content next to an image

Tags: html, css, css-float, image

I have three elements an image, an link and a paragraph, I am wanting have the the image aligned left, and then floating next to that the link and then underneath the link the paragraph, however whatever I try I seem to only be able to get the link to float next to my image, and text just sits underneath the image, how can I make it so the paragraph also floats like my link?

So it needs to look like this,

[image]

Here is my fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/Udders/JjHLa/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the jsfiddle for what you want:

**http://jsfiddle.net/JjHLa/1/**

add this to your css:

```
.field{position:absolute;margin-top:40px;margin-left:85px;}
```

modify your html where your text goes like this(`add class 'field'` to `p tag`):

```
<p class='field'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your link and text in the same `div`. Then you could position the link/text absolutely, and adjust them to perfection, and just float the div.